# Keep last 2 elements of column name seperated by pipe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF which looks like

```
a|b|c|d   e|f|g|h   i|j|k|l
1         4         7
2         5         8
3         6         9
```

I want to transform it to look like

```
|c|d      g|h   k|l
1         4     7
2         5     8
3         6     9
```

When I use the lines below it gives me last or second last one

```
test.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split("|")[-1] , inplace = True)
test.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split("|")[-2] , inplace = True)
```

but when I give it as below it executes but when I do a `test.head()` i get an error

```
test.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split("|")[-2:] , inplace = True)
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Please advise on the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join`, because selecting last 2 values get `list`:

```
test.rename(columns = lambda x: '|'.join(x.split("|")[-2:]) , inplace = True)
print (test)
   c|d  g|h  k|l
0    1    4    7
1    2    5    8
2    3    6    9
```

Another solution, thanks [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830320/keep-last-2-elements-of-column-name-seperated-by-pipe-python-pandas/46830379?noredirect=1#comment80608153_46830379):

```
test.columns = test.columns.str.split('|').str[-2:].str.join('|')
```

Comment: Or `df.columns.str.split('|').str[-2:].str.join('|')` to have the column list.

Comment: Thanks peoples for the solutions